# Using Document.Ready in an MVC Partial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use an MVC Partial to render a JavaScript grid.  To do so, I have to load & utilize jQuery.  However, I keep getting the following error:

> $ is not defined

This should be simple...but apparently...it isn't.

**THE PARTIAL LOOKS LIKE:**

```
<h2>Inside the Partial</h2>

<div id="grid"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" defer>

    // ERROR: $ is not defined
    $(document).ready(function () {
       // Awesome JavaScript Grid Stuff Will Go Here
    });
</script>
```

**THE VIEW LOOKS LIKE:**

```
@using Web.Areas.Administration.ViewModels
@model LookupsViewModel

<h1>View Title</h1>
@Html.Partial(Model.PartialPath, Model.PartialModel)
```

Comment: Scripts should never be in partials. Move you scripts to the main view. And the error means that `jquery-{version}.js` is not loaded.

Comment: Can you also show where you are loading jquery? If your script tags are after the Partial, then jquery won't have even been requested yet by the time $ is called, let alone loaded and ran. I can't speak to whether or not you can run inline jquery in a Partial, as Stephen alluded to.

Comment: Your jQuery file is not loaded before you are usng it , and also move your js code to main view not in partial view

Answer (score 1):

Here are two main things that will help you solve your problem.

1. Make sure that your reference of the jQuery files is correct. Most you could had problem in the path.
2. Don't ever put JavaScripts in the partial views. Put those in parent view before the partial view where it has been called.

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading jquery through script after the Partial view, you will be trying to run jquery variables before they are loaded and defined. Ensure that any jquery that you run (whether inline or not) is run after the page has requested and loaded jquery itself.

See: [Can you write jQuery code inline before loading jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195712/can-you-write-jquery-code-inline-before-loading-jquery)

I'll give a bit more reason why you shouldn't put javascript in your partial views. If you use the Partial more than once, you risk having repeated javascript. That could mean variables are redefined, eventlisteners are added more than once, etc. causing some confusing bugs.